# Angular JS: Cannot read property 'results' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I´m creating an AngularJS app, using the $http service, i´m looping the object and append the second image in the view, the following code does work,and the image is displayed, however, i still get this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of null
    at MegamanController.js:9
    at Object.m [as forEach] (angular.min.js:8)
    at MegamanController.js:7
    at angular.min.js:87
    at angular.min.js:119
    at n.a.$get.n.$eval (angular.min.js:133)
    at n.a.$get.n.$digest (angular.min.js:130)
    at n.a.$get.n.$apply (angular.min.js:133)
    at h (angular.min.js:87)
    at K (angular.min.js:91)
```

Here's the controller:

```
app.controller("MegamanController",function($scope,$http){

$http.get("http://www.ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=2.0&q=megaman+3")
    .success(function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        angular.forEach(data,function(value,key)
        {
            resultados= value.results;
            for(i in resultados)
             {

                imagenes= resultados[i].url;

                una = resultados[1].url;
                console.log(imagenes);

             }
             $(".informacion").append("<img src= '"+una+"'></figure>");
        })

    })
    .error(function(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the response format of the api before creating the success callback.

I think you have to iterate over data.responseData:

```
angular.forEach(data.responseData,function(value,key)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because results objects is inside of responseData object so you need to change this line

```
resultados= value.results;
```

For this

```
resultados= value.responseData.results;
```

[image]